# Preventing compilation of unit test code when necessary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, compilation

I'm working in a C# framework where full compilation can take upwards of an hour. In order to minimize impact, the original design was to pull the unit tests outside of each module's solution and avoid compilation of solutions that end in 'Test'. This design seems to deviate from the standard implementation of unit tests as a separate project within the assembly solution.
If i were to implement unit tests within the solution as a separate project, is there way to tell the compiler to not compile the unit tests in order to save time? The only thing that comes to mind is the Visual Studio Configuration Manager. If i just unchecked the unit test project for a certain configuration (Debug), then i could avoid compilation. But is that the best way to address this?

Comment: You could always "unload" the project. But are you sure you cannot improve build times in other ways? An hour sounds excessive for an incremental build, even if the project is very large. Have you done any measurements to ensure you are optimizing the right things?